# What kind of foundation paint/sealant is this, and how do I replace it?

Tags: paint, foundation, sealing

It appears that the paint near the base of our house that meets the sidewalk outside is peeling and chipping away.

1. What kind of paint/sealant is this?
2. How should I go about repairing it?
3. Should I look to caulk the crack between the wall and sidewalk?

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2, different angle]
[image: A much closer picture]

Comment: If the surface under the chips are smooth, it looks like a "sanded finish " paint. I think it is unlikely though, since outside painting, to my knowledge is not sanded. It may be EIFS (Exterior insulation and finishing system)  but it does not look thick enough. This is left as a comment, since there is not enough info to make an answer. As in what is the surface under the paint? Is it cement, wood, painted? Are the chips that are coming off flexible or brittle?

Comment: The chips are hard, thick, and slightly flexible. I would not call them brittle. I can't really tell what the material underneath is. It seems like another layer of this coating (though not as bumpy), and under that is either wood or cement, not sure as it's not exposed.

Comment: I added the third picture, which is a much closer view of one of the chipped areas.

Comment: although I am far from certain, it appears to be a concrete wall and the hash marks may have been a screen for a parge coat or scratch coat of stucco, covered with a textured coat.   Looks a bit thin for stucco but does look a bit like latex Drylok. Maybe bring a sample to a pro paint store?

Comment: The paint looks like a gloss (it could be any kind of paint really), but from the looks of it (and since it's outside), I would guess it's an oil based paint (I wouldn't be surprized if it was Drylock-brand... but then again I wouldn't be surprized if it wasn't). Fiberglass lath (the screen) is often used when parging. You put a thin layer of cement on the wall, then the screen is pushed on with a trowel, then another thin layer of cement (it's a very common parging method).

Comment: I brought it to a Sherwin Williams retail/contractor store. They were no help at all.